# SQL fill the blank using IIF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have couple columns and several data like this

```
sms_type        ID              fullname
incoming        2036037         NULL
outgoing        2036037         Jason Sayre
```

I like to fill the NULL in fullname column with the same name (Jason Sayre) if ID column match
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by chance you are looking for an UPDATE, here is a little twist on Gordon's answer (+1)

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,NewValue =max(fullname) over (partition by ID) 
 From YourTable
)
Update cte Set FullName=NewValue
  Where FullName is null   -- Where is optional
```

**The Updated Table**

```
sms_type    ID      fullname
incoming    2036037 Jason Sayre
outgoing    2036037 Jason Sayre
```

Comment: Got " Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()` and window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(fullname, max(fullname) over (partition by id)) as imputed_fullname
from t;
```

Comment: Got error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'over'."

Comment: @Tsang there shouldn't be. please check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efb573373532d001abe7cbc81762d764)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following inner join query.

```
create table MyTable(sms_type varchar(20)
, ID float
, fullname varchar(50))

insert into MyTable values
('incoming', 2036037, NULL),
('outgoing', 2036037, 'Jason Sayre')


SELECT MyTable.sms_type
 ,MyTable.ID
 ,ISNULL(MyTable.fullName, tblname.fullName) AS Name
FROM (
    SELECT ID
        ,max(fullname) AS fullName
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY ID
    ) tblname
INNER JOIN MyTable ON MyTable.ID = tblName.ID
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a61710d8f015efcc83c74d5f6b53578c)